# Can we declare a method and use it as a inner method,will all the changes made in the inner method be there?

Tags: java, android

for example

```
public void insert(class_a c) {}

public void database()
{ 
    public void insert(class_a c)
    {
        c.m();
    }
}
```

will the method m will be called?

Comment: It won't be called because it won't even compile.

Comment: If you're making up syntax, *you* should tell us what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you define it in the class inside the method